# JList with changing Height

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jlist

I got a JList, which i want to change height of depended on how many items within the JList.

As seen in the picture, theres alot of components inside a JPanel, which all are alligned at the Y axis. (the JScrollPanel belongs to the JPanel, NOT the JList)

I would like the JList to match its height with the amount of items. A normal JList just stops showing items if it gets too big (unless you apply a JScrollPane).. What i simply want to, is that the JList will get the right size (without hiding items, and without adding a scrollpane).

Best Regards
Oliver

[image: Explenation]

Comment: `" normal JList just stops showing items if it gets too big..."` -- I'm not sure if this is true.

Comment: Yes, your statement above is most definitely false. A JList should size itself to its full height unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Ohh, i might have missed something! I had a setPreferedSize somewhere, and it affected it. Removed it, and now it works! Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Good deal, and glad you've got it working.